# setState is not working with multiple onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate

I have weird issue, and been trying to debug for hours, still can't not find out why.
I have a button onClick, to handle other 2 function, some weird reason the setState one wouldn't work if I have 2 function, if I just keep one function, setState will work, but I need both function.

[Here's my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-j4wvb?fontsize=14)
(And when I reproduce the issue here, it seems work, but the sample it's not update API, it's just change the state)

Thank you for the help!

```
class RecipeReviewCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      expanded: false,
      in: false,
      text: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({ expanded: !state.expanded }));
  };
   /* If I comment out this one, first setState will work */
  handleClick = e => {
    this.setState({ in: !this.state.in });
   /* This come from parent props to update API */
    this.props.updateThing(e.target.value)
  };
```

```
<Button
   className={classes.button}
   onClick={e => this.handleClick()}
>
```

Comment: You're not calling handleExpandClick

Comment: Sorry, I copy the wrong code, I did call `handleClick` for other 2 function, just update my questions. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor, you should call `super(props);` 
see: https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

In your `Button` - you are not passing the event object to your event handler.

```
<Button
   className={classes.button}
   onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)} // note the e here.
>
```

Since your `handleClick` function is already bound to your component instance, you should just provide it to `onClick` handler directly without writing that arrow function, like so:

```
<Button
   className={classes.button}
   onClick={this.handleClick}
>
```